# Concering the proof of the Naimark Duality Theorem (Frames, Riesz bases)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Naimark Duality Theorem: Let $(\varphi_{i})_{i \in I} \subset \mathcal H$. Then $(\varphi_{i})_{i \in I}$ is a frame iff $\exists$ a Hilbert space $\mathcal K \supset \mathcal H$ and a Riesz Basis $(\psi_{i})_{i \in I}$ for $\mathcal K$ s.t. $\mathcal P_{\mathcal H}\psi_i = \varphi_i$ for all $i \in I$ where $\mathcal P_{\mathcal H}$ is as usual the orthogonal projection of $\mathcal K$ onto $\mathcal H$.

Concerning $\Rightarrow$, the proof starts as follows: Since $(\varphi_{i})_{i \in I}$ is a frame, there is a result that states that the analysis operator $T$ maps $\mathcal H$ bijectively onto a closed subset of $\ell_2(I)$ which we denote by $\mathcal M$. Consider $V: \mathcal M \to \mathcal H, Vc := T^*c$, where $T^*$ the synthesis operator (and adjoint of $T$).

Now let $(e_{i})_{i \in I}$ be the standard orthonormal basis. Since $\ker T^*= \ker P_{\mathcal M} = \mathcal M^⊥$, $V \mathcal P_{\mathcal M} e_i =T^{*} P_{\mathcal M} e_i = T^*e_i = \varphi_i$.

So basically, $e_i$ lies in $\mathcal M$ for all $i \in I$ and $\mathcal M$ is a closed subset of $\ell_2(I)$, then I would follow that $\mathcal M = \ell_2(I)$? That wouldn't make sense.

Comment: How does the third paragraph imply the fourth? What part of $V\mathcal{P}_Me_i=\varphi_i$ tells you that $e_i\in \mathcal{M}$?

Comment: This might be where I am mistaken but since $\mathcal P_{M}$ is a projection onto $M$, I would expect there exists some $J \subset I$ such that $P_{M}e_j = 0$ for all $j \in J$.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. In your fourth paragraph, you say that $e_i\in \mathcal{M}$ for all $i\in I$. What part of your preceding discussion led you to that conclusion?

Comment: Because $T^*P_{M}e_i = T^*e_i$, i.e. no $e_i$ is in the kernel of $P_M$.

Comment: Not being in the kernel of $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}$ does not mean you are in $\mathcal{M}$. Just look at the two dimensional projection on $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is the $x$-axis. Then $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ isn't in the kernel of $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}$, but it also isn't in $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: $\ell_2(I)=\mathcal{M}\oplus\mathcal{M}^\perp$, which means each $x\in \ell_2(I)$ can be written as $y+x$, where $y\in \mathcal{M}$ and $z\in \mathcal{M}^\perp$. 

If $y=0$, then $x=y+z$ lies in $\mathcal{M}^\perp=\ker \mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}$. 

If $z=0$, then $x=y+z$ lies in $\mathcal{M}$. 

But if neither $y$ nor $z$ is zero, then $x$ is neither in $\mathcal{M}$ nor $\ker \mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: But then which 'part' of $e_i$ (standard ONB) lies (or can lie) in $\mathcal M$?

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to answer that without knowing what the frame is. It could be many different things. But I also don't think that knowing what $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M} e_i$ is should be necessary for the proof.

Comment: Let $(w_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers such that $\sum w_i=1$ and $\sum_i w_i^2<\infty$. Let $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{R}$ with basis $(z)$ and let $x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty w_ie_i\in \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$. We can make a frame for $\mathcal{H}$ by $f_i=w_i z$. Then in this case $\mathcal{M}$ is the one-dimensional span of $x$ in $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$. Then for any $i\in \mathbb{N}$, $$\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}e_i=\frac{w_i}{\sum_j w_j^2} x.$$  By such examples, we can get many different things for $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}e_i$.

Comment: But why does then $T^* P_M e_i = T^* e_i$ hold?

Comment: Why wouldn't it hold?

Comment: Because $P_M e_i$ is not equal $e_i$ as you said so $T^*$ doesn't work with the whole information of $e_i$.

Comment: Since $\mathcal{M}$ comes from the operator $T$, in some sense the operator $T$ already knows what $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}$ is doing, so it doesn't need to know the whole information of $e_i$. 

More specifically, for any continuous, linear operator $B:\mathcal{H}_1\to X$ from a Hilbert space into another space $X$, we can write $\mathcal{H}_1=\ker(B)\oplus \ker(B)^\perp$. Then $B$ kills the part of the vector in $\ker(B)$, and only needs to know the part of the vector in $\ker(B)^\perp$.

Comment: In this situation, both $T^*$ and $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}$ kill the part of the vector in $\mathcal{M}^\perp$ and only need to know the part of the vector in $\mathcal{M}$ to assign the value. Then $T^*=T^*\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}$, because including the projection only strips away the part of the vector in $\mathcal{M}^\perp$, which $T^*$ was just going to strip away anyway.

Comment: But then why $T^*P_M e_i = \varphi_i$? I mean $T^*e_i = \varphi_i$ is clear which is straightforward pluggin in but $T^*$ as you say only works with the part of $e_i$ that is not eliminated.

Comment: Because including the projection only strips away the part of the vector in $M^\perp$, which $T^∗$ was just going to strip away anyway. For this reason, including the projection before applying $T^*$ does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B:X\to \mathcal{H}$ be any continuous linear operator between Hilbert spaces and let $\mathcal{R}$ be the closure of the range $B(X)$. Then we can write $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{R}\oplus \mathcal{R}^\perp$. Then if we think about the adjoint, standard techniques tell us that $\ker(B^*)=\mathcal{R}^\perp$.

Now let us write vectors in $\mathcal{H}$ as $(x,y)\in \mathcal{R}\oplus \mathcal{R}^\perp$, where $x\in \mathcal{R}$ and $y\in \mathcal{R}^\perp$. Then $B^*(x,y)=(B^*x,0)$. That is, since $\ker(B)=\mathcal{R}^\perp$, $B^*$ kills the part of $(x,y)$ which is in $\mathcal{R}^\perp$ (which is just $y$), and the value of $B^*$ on $(x,y)$ onlyl depends on $x$.

Now the projection $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}$ on $\mathcal{H}$ has the action $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}(x,y)=(x,0)$. So $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}$ just kills the part of the vector in $\mathcal{R}^\perp$ and keeps the part in $\mathcal{R}$. Then for any $(x,y)$, $$B^*(x,y)=(B^*x,0)$$ and $$B^*\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}(x,y)=B^*(x,0)=(B^*x,0).$$  So $B^*=B^*\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}$. To explain this in words, if $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}$ is the projection onto the closure of the range of $B$, then $B^*=B^*\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}$. This is because $B^*$ only needs to know the part of the vector in $\mathcal{R}$ ($x$ above) and it does not matter what the part of the vector in $\mathcal{R}^\perp$ is ($y$ above) because $B^*$ is just going to send the $y$ to zero anyway. Therefore including the projection $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}$ before $B^*$ only has the effect of keeping the $x$, which is all $B^*$ is acting on anyway. So including the projection $\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}$ doesn't change anything, and $B^*=B^*\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{R}$. This is a general phenomenon and doesn't have anything to do with frames. Apply this with $B=T$, $B^*=V$, and $\mathcal{H}=\ell_2(I)$, and $\mathcal{R}=\mathcal{M}$.

To answer your question, everything you have written in your first three paragraphs is correct. But what you have written in the first three paragraphs DOES NOT imply that $e_i\in \mathcal{M}$. By the first part of my answer, $T^*\mathcal{P}_\mathcal{M}x=x$ for ALL $x$, but this does not imply that $x\in \mathcal{M}$. This can also be seen by the two dimensional example I gave in the comments.